# Python not able to send a POST request

Tags: python, api, post

I am trying to post a data using python using its `request` module but always keeps getting error. If I use the same data to post to API using `postman`, I am getting `201` response which is good. Here is the python code:

```
import requests

json_data = open(config_file)
config_data = json.load(json_data)
json_data.close()

############################
# some code to get health_data
############################
health_data = json.dumps(health_data)

try:
    log.error("Posting data to API")
    response = requests.post(config_data["API"], data=health_data)
    log.error(response.status_code, response.reason)
except Exception as e:
    log.error(e)
```

I have all the configuration saved in a `config.json` file. `health_data` is the data which I am converting into a json format using `json.dumps`. When I am posting this `health_data` to API, I always get 500. But if I post the same `health_data` to API using `postman`, I get the `201` response code, so I think something is wrong with the python code. I think something is wrong with this line:

```
response = requests.post(config_data["API"], data=health_data)
```

I have also tried using `json` instead of `data` as I have json data, like below:

```
response = requests.post(config_data["API"], json=health_data)
```

But it throws same 500 error.

Can anyone please point me to the right direction. Many thanks.

**health_data:**

```
{
    "macs": "44ead844c9d1",
    "aTime": "2018-08-09T19:04:01Z",
    "startTime": "2018-08-09T19:04:01Z",
    "stopTime": "2018-08-29T18:19:48Z",
    "data1": ["2018-08-09T19:04:02Z : 26.62", "2018-08-09T19:19:02Z : 27.82", "2018-08-29T18:04:19Z : 18.79", "2018-08-29T18:19:48Z : 20.26"],
    "data2": ["2018-08-09T19:04:02Z : 63.83", "2018-08-09T19:19:02Z : 59.16", "2018-08-09T19:34:02Z : 58.73", "2018-08-29T18:04:19Z : 100", "2018-08-29T18:19:48Z : 85.51"]
}
```

Comment: Does your server give you some clues on what went wrong, perhaps?

Comment: Post data as it in Postman. I think a problem with structure *data1* and *data2* fields(is it array of strings or array of objects?)

Comment: @sKwa It is array.

Comment: i think you should compare the different between 2 request (requests,postman) by using Fiddler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it by not using the json message to post data. I have used dict() in python and posted data using :

```
response = requests.post(config_data["API"], json=health_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

What do the commands you are using mean:

```
>>> help(open)
Open a file for reading in text mode and return a stream

>>> help(json.load)
Deserialize a .read()-supporting file-like object containing a JSON document to a Python object.

>>> help(json.dumps)
Serialize `obj` to a JSON formatted `str`

>>> help(requests.post)
post(url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs)
    Sends a POST request.

    :param data: (optional) Dictionary (will be form-encoded), bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
    :param json: (optional) json data to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
```

From this information: you can get away with the `open`, `json.load` and the `request.post` with the `data` parameter.